# Why isn't docker-compose seeing my .env file when executing an ssh command inside a bash script?

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

When i ssh to `server.foo`.com as user `fish` and execute docker-compose up, docker will see a corresponding .env file that sites the the same directory.

```
[fish@staging-core ~]$ ls -al
total 28
drwx------. 4 fish fish  191 Jun 18 21:47 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root   root     34 Jun 18 20:35 ..
-rw-------. 1 fish fish  558 Jun 18 22:15 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--. 1 fish fish   18 Apr 11 00:53 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 fish fish  193 Apr 11 00:53 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. 1 fish fish  231 Apr 11 00:53 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--. 1 fish fish    0 Jun 18 20:19 .cloud-locale-test.skip
drwx------. 2 fish fish   25 Jun 18 21:41 .docker
-rw-r--r--. 1 fish fish  838 Jun 18 22:15 .env
-rw-r--r--. 1 fish fish 1066 Jun 18 22:15 docker-compose.yml
drwx------. 2 fish fish   29 Jun 18 20:35 .ssh
```

However, when i try and run this via a bash script, i get the following error:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null fish@server.foo.com docker-compose down && docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d && docker-compose scale api=4 && docker-compose scale ml=4
```

I get

```
Warning: Permanently added 'server.foo.com,165.227.100.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Removing network core_default
Network core_default not found.
WARNING: The FISH_TAG variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Why isn't docker-compose seeing my .env file when executing an ssh command inside a bash script?

Comment: Did you try wrapping all the chained instructions with double quotes ? It seems like only the first instruction is executed into the remote server, but the rest of it is executed on the local shell

Comment: @ArthurAttout you were just ahead of me :-) Indeed it is a quoting problem, everything after "&&" executes on the host machine, so the error message reported comes from local docker-compose! I'd suggest you to add this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double-quote your command, otherwise the chained instructions will execute on the local shell

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null fish@server.foo.com 
 "docker-compose down && \
 docker-compose pull && \
 docker-compose up -d && \
 docker-compose scale api=4 && \
 docker-compose scale ml=4"
```